# Find $\mathsf{E}\left[(X_1+X_2)^4\mid X_1-X_2\right]$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid standard normal

Tags: probability

Find $$\mathsf{E}\left[(X_1+X_2)^4\mid X_1-X_2\right]$$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. standard normal.

I know that both $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are both distributed $N(0,2)$. I'm having trouble finding the joint p.df of $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ so that I can use it to compute the conditional pdf in order to help find the expectation.

Comment: I would suggest to first determine whether $Y=X_1+X_2$ and $Z=X_1-X_2$ are correlated or not, by calculating their covariance. Then, to think whether you can ascertain that they are jointly normally distributed or not.

Comment: To find the joint pdf, see that $(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)$ can be obtained by a linear transformation (matrix product) from $(X_1,X_2)$, hence they are jointly normal. You only need to compute the covariance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_+ = X_1+X_2$ and $Y_- = X_1 - X_2$. Since $(Y_-, Y_+)$ are jointly normal as a linear combination of jointly normal random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, their pdf is determined by their mean and covariance.

Clearly
$$
    \mathsf{E}\left(Y_\pm\right) = 0
$$
$$
   \mathbb{Var}\left(Y_\pm\right) = \mathsf{E}\left(\left(X_1 \pm X_2\right)^2\right) = \mathsf{E}\left(X_1^2\right) \pm 2 \mathsf{E}\left(X_1\right) \mathsf{E}\left(X_2\right) + \mathsf{E}\left(X_2^2 \right) = 2
$$
and 
$$
   \mathbb{Cov}(Y_-, Y_+) = \mathsf{E}\left(X_1^2 - X_2^2\right) = 0
$$
Hence $(Y_-, Y_+)$ are *independent* Gaussian with zero mean and variance of 2. Thus
$$
   \mathsf{E}\left(Y_+^4 \mid Y_-\right) = \mathsf{E}\left(Y_+^4\right) = 3 \sigma^4 = 12
$$

Comment: why does a zero covariance imply independence? This is not true in general.

Comment: @mtiano Jointly Gaussian random variables with zero covarinance are independent. This is generally not true  for other joint distributions.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide a reference for this, I'm interested in the argument.

Comment: @mtiano This is mentioned on [wikipedia's MVN-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normally_distributed_and_independent). In general this follows from the characeristic function of bivariate normal distribution $$ \mathsf{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i u_1 X_1 + i u_2 X_2} \right) = \exp\left( i \sum_{k=1}^2 \mu_k u_k - \sum_{k=1}^2 (\sigma_k u_k)^2/2 - \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 u_1 u_2 \right) $$ If $\rho=0$ the characteristic function factors into a product of univariate normal random variables.